# Is it possible to find one's answers after deleting the account?

Tags: support

I wonder if it's possible to find all of a user's answers and statistics (activity etc) if the account has been deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you know the user's ID (it's included in the URL of a user profile):

- ♦ moderators have the ability to see a list of posts (questions and answers, not comments) by a deleted user
- If the deletion was this week, you can use [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/buddhism/query/1258002/posts-by-user?UserId=8527) to find a list of posts (your account is not deleted, but you get the idea)
- If it's longer ago, you can use the quarterly [data dump](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange)
- If you're lucky, the user's profile has been [saved in the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20200702051415/https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/users/8527/ruslan).